# Which method is Fast and good method(s) to Add selected values into a datagrid

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagrid

for Example,in a form using following controls

- combobox(`cboProducts`)
- textbox(`txtQty`)
- trueDBGrid( uisng Component One Control) (`grdSale`)

so,
`cboProducts` is filling with Product_name,Product_Id from Products table,
once a Product is select(`cboProducts`) then next step is to enter the quantity (`txtQty`)
after enterting the qty the grid should be filled with the above entered items.

*My Plan*

adds the entering Product,Qty into `Datatbale` and then `Datatable` to my `grdSale`

i think there will be another good method is available, i hope good answers

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use something like this,
this assumes that the columns are defined

```
    grdSale.Rows.Clear()

    For Each item As myObject In MyObjects

        Dim row As New DataGridViewRow
        row.CreateCells(grdSale)

        row.Cells(0).Value = item.PKId
        row.Cells(1).Value = item.Product_Desc
        row.Cells(2).Value = item.Quantity
        row.Cells(3).Value = item.Price

        item.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

GridView uses a datasource. In your case it uses a datatable as it's source.
(I'm a c# developer so syntax could be a little off)

```
Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
dt = GetDataFromDB()

gridView.DataSource = dt
```

When you successfully create events for your controls, you should just add new row to your datatable and the changes will be visible in the grid.

```
Sub AddRow(byval productID as Integer, byval productName as string, byval qty as Integer)
  dim row as System.Data.DataRow
  row = dt.NewRow()  'this gets a fresh row from the datatable. Since you already have the datatable defined, the for will have the appropriate columns for your data

  row("productID") = productID
  row("productName") = productName
  row("qry") = qry

  dt.Rows.Add(row) ' at this line you add the new row to the datatable which is "viewed" by a grid and which in turn shows the new information inside itself.

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
Private Sub cboProducts_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles cboProducts.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim pdt, pdtid As String
        Dim i As Integer
        pdt = cboProducts.Columns(0).Text
        pdtid = cboProducts.Columns(1).Text.ToString
        grdSale.SetDataBinding()
        If grdSale.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            i = 0
        Else
            i = i + grdSale.Rows.Count
        End If
        grdSale.AddRows(1)
        grdSale(i, 0) = pdt
        grdSale(i, 1) = pdtid
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: its a good attempt but you must call `grdSale.SetDataBinding()` only once that means better use it `Load Event`